# Can you create your own Enum type in SQLite in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hello I'm working on a **Management Restaurants project** on Android Studio using Java , and since  I have **6 types of categories** , I want to group them on a specific type in my `Database table` like we do in `MySQL Enum` type , and of course access to them later .
Here's my table code on Java, and I'm using `SQLite` as a database :

```
public static final String CREATE_RESTAURANT_TABLE_ =
            "CREATE TABLE  " + RESTAURANT_TABLE + "(" +
                    ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    NAME + " TEXT " +
                    CITY + " TEXT " +
                    CATEGORY + "TEXT" +
                    PHONE_NUMBER + "TEXT"  +
                    LAT + "TEXT" +
                    LON + " TEXT );";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `ENUM` data type in SQLite, but even if there was one it would not be the best way to define this column.
What if you want to add a new category? You would have to redefine the enum values in the table's definition and this is not possible in SQLite unless you recreate the table (as you can find [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)).

The proper design in this case is to create a table `categories` like:

```
CREATE TABLE categories(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, category TEXT);
```

and store all the categories there:

```
INSERT INTO categories(category) VALUES 
  ('category1'),   ('category2'), ....,   ('categoryn');
```

and in your `RESTAURANT_TABLE` define a column that references the column `id` of `categories`:

```
public static final String ID_CATEGORY = "id_category";
public static final String CREATE_RESTAURANT_TABLE_ =
            "CREATE TABLE  " + RESTAURANT_TABLE + "(" +
                    ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    NAME + " TEXT," +
                    CITY + " TEXT," +
                    ID_CATEGORY + " INTEGER REFERENCES categories(id)," +
                    PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT,"  +
                    LAT + " TEXT," +
                    LON + " TEXT);";
```

In your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class you must enable foreign key constraints by overriding `onConfigure()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

Now, in the column `id_category` of the restaurants table you will store ids which are references to the categories that you have in the `categories` table.
You can add new categories in `categories` without any problem.

When you query the table restaurants and you want to retrieve each row's category you must join the 2 tables:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.city, c.category, r.phone_number, r.lat, r.long
FROM restaurants AS r INNER JOIN categories AS c
ON c.id = r.id_category
```